# How to get Quick Look to print PDF files double-sided?

Tags: printing, quicklook

My default printer's default settings are to print double-sided. It works well in all apps, due to system-wide preferences… with the exception of Quick Look: when I open a file with Quick Look (pressing space bar in Finder), then ask it to print (Command-P), it does not open a dialog and send it directly to the printer, **one-sided**.

How can I configure this behavior? Or is there another shortcut to get the behavior I want?

Comment: Whats stopping you from double clicking and opening the file properly to print, is there a reason why it has to be printed through quick look??

Comment: @I'msuperawesome it's fewer keystrokes! (or mouse clicks)  Quick Look is already part of my workflow when I sift through files… not having to open it in Preview, then close Preview, is quite nice

Answer (score -1):

If you are on Mountain Lion when u use quick-look and press **Command-P** to print the document. The "*Quick-look App*" actually opens the document in "*Preview App*" and make a **simple print**.
I advise you to open the document in preview directly to print it **double-sided**.